# How do I show 'emphasis' in the following Japanese sentence?

Tags: translation, semantics, japanese

I'm translating this old book I have from Japanese to English, and I was wondering how to 'add emphasis' in English.

> 背後で聞き覚えのある声**がして**、　思わずー歩後ずさってしまった。

A rough translation is:

> I sense behind me a certain voice I remember hearing before, so I instinctively retreat with one step forward.

I think in the above instance the して is being used to emphasis, as defined by the [fourth definition](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6) on Jisho.org, shown below.

> 1. by (indicating means of action); as (a group, etc.)​
> 2. indicates patient of a causative expression​ - as 〜をして in modern Japanese
> 3. acts as a connective - ​after the ren'youkei form of an adjective
>
> **4. adds emphasis - ​after an adverb or a particle**

How do I show 'emphasis' on what's already translated in English?

**EDIT: Apparently I messed up on my original translation, and what I thought was a emphasis particle is actually a verb. Sorry for posting when my knowledge was incorrect.**

Comment: For the benefit of non-Japanese speakers, what word or phrase is being emphasized in the original?

Comment: Not that it has any authority, but Google translate gives for the second phrase "I suddenly got lost after walking." That said "take one step forward in retreat" is either very poetic, or very counterintuitive. Did you mean 'backward'?

Comment: @Mitch If the voice is behind you, then you'd have to retreat forward.

Comment: What do you want to emphasize???

Comment: @MarkBeadles Oh... yes, you'd have to go forwards. But that is surely not a retreat. Retreat and forwards do not mix.

Comment: @Mitch you just gave a perfect example as to why I don't use google translate. I had to add the 'forward' there as a gloss over, as the word 'retreat' implies moving backwards, and seeing as how the voice is coming from behind, the only proper way to retreat would be to take a single step forward. The other words available on https://jisho.org/word/後ずさる didn't fit for the context of the situation.

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Sure, google translate has its difficulties (which should explain why I said "Not that it has any authority"). I only gave that for a baseline reference for those who don't know Japanese (like myself). But I do know English and re "the only proper way" is not how I would describe this situation. Logic doesn't always work. In this (or any) context to retreat forward is a solecism, unnatural or a glaring oxymoron. That may be the effect you want in English, but I doubt it was intended by the author of the original.

Comment: I could have worded my comment better. I meant 'logical way' instead of proper way, but forgot the word logical existed. Brain farts are really horrible. I agree that its a oxymoron, and that the author intended something else in the original, I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: ...could be a Sun Tsu thing: "Attack to the rear and be crushed from in front..."

Comment: @cascabel HA, I WISH the narrator had enough SENSE to think that far, but seeing as how this is the same Dork who, upon waking up in a unfamiliar room after a life and death battle that resulted in him being knocked out, first action is to comment on the Décor, I don't think he does. lol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what OP thought was a emphasis particle is actually a verb.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Would it be better for me to just delete the question/close it myself and save you and others the trouble of voting to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the word *do* for emphasis in that case. Looking at [TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/do), we see that *do* is

> 2. Used as a means of emphasis: *I do want to be sure.*

You can put that emphasis in a couple of places.

> Behind me comes a certain voice I *do* remember ...

or

> Behind me *does* come a certain voice I remember ...

Of the two I prefer the first.

Reasoning: Since して is used to add emphasis and is an inflected form of する, and the bare verb form (する) has some pretty strong equivalence to the English auxiliary verb *do*, this feels like the best way to add emphasis without muddying the meaning of the original Japanese.

Comment: I actually went and changed my translation to "I sense behind me a certain voice I remember hearing before, so I instinctively take one step forward in retreat." as Chocolate answered here. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68046/what-does-emphasis-mean-in-the-がして-of-the-following-sentence